# Login to old Firefox Sync Account

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I just reset my windows 8 and Installed Firefox 36. But when I logged in to Sync account, all of my old data was gone. Nothing synced and now I have a sync account which is syncing it's own data.

My old passwords and bookmarks are gone.

Is there any possible way to access my old data?

Answer (score 2):

You can check your firefox account information [here](https://account.services.mozilla.com/), if there is bookmarks on the cloud but just can't sync to your firefox, you can download it back

Comment: "Unable to locate your account. Please check your username. "  This is what it says when I enter the correct e-mail address.

Comment: No one can help if you can't remember you own account login credential. If you reset your account password with linked email [Details](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ive-lost-my-firefox-sync-account-information)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. The thing is when I logged in with the Firefox-36 ( after resetting windows 8 and re-installing Firefox), I didn't create a new sync account, it logged me in without any problem. I have read other blogs too and it seems you are thinking it as "Old Sync" and "New Sync" problem. I remember all my usernames and passwords, but it still is not logging me in on your given URL neither it is accepting any of my E-Mail address for "Forgot Password" page.

Comment: Also does changing the name of Device and Username of the Windows user affects Firefox-Sync? If that is the case it might be the problem because I accidentally changed my Device and Windows User name.